# Calcular la diferencia entre dos dataframes en Python

Tags: python, pandas

Quiero calcular la diferencia porcentual entre el numero de barcos antes de covid, despues de covid, y su impacto.

Tengo creado los dataframes df_agg_pandemia y df_agg_postpandemia. Cada uno de ellos tiene un campo Month, State, Embarcaciones (Prepandemia / PostPandemia ). Las embarcaciones es un count.

Lo que yo quiero es calcular una diferencia porcentual : (df_agg_prepandemia - df_agg_pandemia) / df_agg_prepandemia *100

El momento de hacer alguna resta o divisiòn entre df_agg_postpandemia -df_agg_pandemia, me aparece error.

````
df_agg_prepandemia = pd.DataFrame()
i = 0
for row in df_prepandemia:
    df_agg_prepandemia.loc[i, 'month'] = row['_id']['month']
    df_agg_prepandemia.loc[i, 'state'] = row['_id']['state']
    df_agg_prepandemia.loc[i, 'count'] = row['count']
    i += 1    

df_agg_prepandemia = df_agg_prepandemia.rename(columns={'count': 'embarcaciones_prepandemia'})    

# ¿Que tanto afectó la pandemia al tráfico por mes:

df_afectacion = pd.DataFrame ```
````

Comment: ¿qué error te aparece? ¿Qué relación guarda el código que has puesto con tu pregunta? ¿Dónde está en tu código la operación que te da error?

Comment: Utilizo una resta sencilla. (diferencia : df_agg_prepandemia -df_agg_pandemia ) . El error que me aparece es  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, is_cmp)
    141     try:
--> 142         result = expressions.evaluate(op, left, right)
    143     except TypeError:

Comment: Lo que yo quiero es calcular una diferencia porcentual : (df_agg_prepandemia - df_agg_pandemia) / df_agg_prepandemia *100

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad! Por favor edita tu pregunta agregando esta información y cualquier otro antecedente para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.